# How do you run a membership/event report?

Tags: civievent, civimember, reports

To be considered a 'voting' member in our organization, you have to be an active member, and also have attended a certain number of events in the past year. I see how to run a membership report, and I see how to run an event report, but how can I search for 'active member' AND 'attended 3 events in the last 12 months'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several answers to this; I'll give you three!  Use whichever works best for you.

Note that I originally thought that either [Summary Fields](https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields) or [Event Count custom search](https://github.com/progressivetech/net.ourpowerbase.search.eventcount) extensions would be part of this solution, but neither can count only events in the last 12 months without modification.

#### Easy, best for now

Search for active members.  Add them to a group.  Run the event report, filtering by the Active Member group.  If you need to run this report regularly, the Active Member group should be a smart group.

#### Coming soon

There's an alpha version of the [Search overhaul](https://civicrm.org/blog/josh/overhauling-search-and-reporting-in-civicrm) that ships (disabled and hidden) in CiviCRM 5.28 (which released three days ago).  This will allow doing searches like you describe in a single search pretty easily.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will use the easy option for now, and track the search overhaul as it matures! Thank you Jon.